# FileSizeLimitExceededException leads to error 500 instead of 413

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, error-handling

I got an exception like

> 2018-11-01 21:05:49.122 ERROR 31446 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException: Maximum upload size exceeded; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field file exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1024 bytes.] with root cause
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field file exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1024 bytes.

why 413 http error wasn't raised automatically?

Answer (score 3):

You have to define maximum file size for a file upload.

Add below properties in application.properties

`spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=128KB`
`spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=128KB`

For spring boot 2.

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=128MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=128MB
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748022/multipart-file-maximum-size-exception-spring-boot-embbeded-tomcat)

Comment: I already set these params and it set limitations properly, but it responds with status 500.

Comment: refer this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298265/maxuploadsizeexceededexception-doesnt-invoke-the-exception-handling-method-in-s

Comment: @AlexKorotkov also add `server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=-1`