# Spring Boot - Multipart file maximum upload size exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm developing a endpoint with Spring Boot **2.1.3** (using the standard Tomcat embedded web server) to upload an image and I want to limit the size of the multipart upload. I can do this easily with the properties:

```
spring:
    servlet:
        multipart:
            max-file-size: 2MB
            max-request-size: 2MB
```

But I always get a 500 that Spring can't catch because is Tomcat that is throwing the exception and the request don't reach my code in the RestController.

```
2019-03-02 10:12:50.544 ERROR [] [   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]] [] Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException: Maximum upload size exceeded; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (3917946) exceeds the configured maximum (2097152)] with root cause 
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (3917946) exceeds the configured maximum (2097152)
```

My ExceptionHandler is like this but obviously don't work whatever the exception that put in the annotation:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
public ResponseEntity handleMaxSizeException(Exception e) {
    logger.warn(e.getMessage());
    ...
    return status(HttpStatus.PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE).body(...);
}
```

I already tried this with the already mentioned properties but without any effect:

```
@Bean
public TomcatServletWebServerFactory containerFactory() {
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    factory.addConnectorCustomizers((TomcatConnectorCustomizer) connector -> 
        ((AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>) connector.getProtocolHandler()).setMaxSwallowSize(-1));
    return factory;
}
```

I already checked the answers in the following questions (and others...) but they are mostly outdated or simply don't work:

- [Multipart file maximum size exception - spring boot embbeded tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748022/multipart-file-maximum-size-exception-spring-boot-embbeded-tomcat)
- [MaxUploadSizeExceededException doesn't invoke the exception handling method in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298265/maxuploadsizeexceededexception-doesnt-invoke-the-exception-handling-method-in-s)
- [How to handle MaxUploadSizeExceededException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689989/how-to-handle-maxuploadsizeexceededexception)

Is somebody struggling with this?

Comment: I run into this after following suggestions :  [ERR] Resource exhaustion event: the JVM was unable to allocate memory from the heap.

Answer (score 14):

Please add this in your `application.properties`:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=50MB
```

You can change the size as you need in the above config

Comment: Thanks for your help but you should read carefully the question. On the first paragraph I already said that I have tried those properties.

Comment: `50Mb` doesn't work for me. I get `failed to convert java.lang.String to org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize`.

Comment: it should be 'MB' instead of 'Mb'

Comment: This worked great for me with a similar problem, but only with capital B, as mentioned

Answer (score 6):

A bit late. You need set in application.properties or application.yml 
`server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=-1`
With it tomcat will not interferred in the upload request and the operation will be handle fully by spring and your exception controller will work perfectly. 
[References](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-file-upload-and-connection-reset-issue/)

Answer (score 0):

Was having a similar problem.  Tomcat kept complaining that the request was exceeding the configured maximum (2097152), even though I had the default settings in place in the global web.xml:

```
      <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
      <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
```

Finally figured out: the servlet class I am developing extends a servlet class that has the @MultipartConfig annotation, but my local class did not have the @MultipartConfig annotation. So the request was not being treated as multi-part, which was tripping this error.

The code that was throwing the error is in the super class at these lines:

```
//Search through the parts for an uploaded file
for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
```